# Set function parameters in an asynchronous way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following function where I experience that the function launch sometimes is called without a params.name set. I am not that strong in async functions, so I am wondering if this could be because setName does not necessarily return before launch is called?
And would it then help to put the function call inside a ternary in the initialization of `self.params`?

```
projectLaunch: function(options) {
  var self = this;
  if (options.name === null || options.name === "undefined") {
    var name = self.setName();
  } else { 
    var name = options.name;
  };

   self.params = {
     name: name
   };
  launch(self.params);
},

setName = function() {
  return encodeBase64(User.name, Project.name)
}
```

This is all part of a larger object and the function projectLaunch is called externally.

Comment: Your edited code doesn't compile. Can you build a minimal working example so that we can look for your problem.

Comment: this: `options.name === null || options.name === "undefined"` should be this: `options.name === null || options.name === undefined`, or just this: `options.name == null` (double instead of triple `==`)

Comment: Right, that is a typo as well. I am actually checking for falsy with a `options.name == null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing asynchronous here (I don't have the implementation of your `encodeBase64` but I don't see why it would be asynchronous).

But this doesn't assign the function to any name nor does it call it :

```
function(options) {
...
}
```

So `launch` can't be called from the code we see.

If you want to make an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), fix it as

```
(function(options) {
...
})({});
```

---

If you're expecting a non empty string in `options.name`, the simplest solution to use the passed value or another one is this :

```
var name = options.name || self.setName();
```

Comment: In fact... the code is strange. It looks like it was copied from something more complex...

Comment: This code was an answer to the precedent version of the code. I'm waiting for a fixed question before I edit my answer.

Comment: Well, this basically answers my question. I just needed to know if `setName()` could return after `launch()` was called. If that's not the case then my error must be somewhere else.

Comment: the system made a good point : you don't test correctly if `options.name` is defined. See my suggestion in the edited answer.